# Is there a way to paste a matrix cell-by-cell in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, matrices

I would like to paste a matrix in Lyx, just like it was a table (edit->paste special, etc), except into a display math matrix.

Any ideas?  I can't get it to work, though pasting into tables works fine.

Tx!

Comment: If you don't find a solution, consider making an enhancement request at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: This appears to be borderline off-topic to me. While LyX questions are in general ok, this seems to be asking for "LyX hacks" which are just too much for this site. As it has been suggested before, LyX's official support might be a better place for this.